# If statement not working & user validation?

Tags: c#, validation, if-statement

I can't figure out what I am doing wrong. What I am trying to do is get user input and validate that it is a number, between 1-4, and nothing else crashes the program. But I can't get the tryparse number validation to work. It wont run the code inside. Any integers outside of 1 and 5 don't throw errors, but entering decimals, strings, etc., do. Its an obvious fix but I cant seem to figure it out.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        string[] ColorsArray = new string[12] { "blue", "red", "green", "yellow", "blue", "green", "blue", "yellow", "red", "green", "red", "yellow" };


        float[] LengthArray = new float[12] { 1.3f, 1.4f, 5.6f, 1.5f, 3.5f, 5.4f, 1.2f, 6.5f, 4.4f, 4.1f, 3.3f, 4.9f };




            Console.WriteLine("Select a color of Fish by entering the corresponding number \r\n 1. Blue \r\n 2. Yellow \r\n 3. Red \r\n 4. Green");
            string ColorChoiceNumber = Console.ReadLine();

            int ColorChoiceNumberInt = int.Parse(ColorChoiceNumber);




            if (ColorChoiceNumberInt == 1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The Biggest Blue Fish is Fish Number ");

            }
           else if (ColorChoiceNumberInt == 2)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The Biggest Yellow Fish is Fish Number");
            }
           else if (ColorChoiceNumberInt == 3)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The Biggest Red Fish is Fish Number");
            }
            else if (ColorChoiceNumberInt == 4)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The Biggest Green Fish is Fish Number");
            }

            else if (!(int.TryParse(ColorChoiceNumber, out ColorChoiceNumberInt)) && ColorChoiceNumberInt < 1 && ColorChoiceNumberInt > 4)
            {

                Console.WriteLine("Please only enter a number. It must be 1-4.");
                ColorChoiceNumber = Console.ReadLine();
                int.TryParse(ColorChoiceNumber, out ColorChoiceNumberInt);



            }
            else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please only enter a number. It must be 1-4.");
            ColorChoiceNumber = Console.ReadLine();
            int.TryParse(ColorChoiceNumber, out ColorChoiceNumberInt);
        }



        }




    }
```

}

Comment: You need to use `int.TryParse`, which tells you whether or not the parsing succeeds. If you provide anything *except* an integer in the form of a string to `int.TryParse`, it will throw an exception.

Comment: _"I can't get the tryparse number validation to work"_ -- it would work if you used it. You're not calling `TryParse()` until it's too late. You've already called `Parse()`, which just throws an exception if passed an invalid string to parse (I assume that's what @Rob meant to say...`TryParse()` isn't going to throw an exception here).

Comment: thank you, i swear i did it that way but it wasn't working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, to get valid input from the user, you just need to do a few things:

1. Declare the `int` variable before calling `int.TryParse`
2. Pass the variable as the second `out` parameter to `int.TryParse`
3. Put the code to check the return value of `int.TryParse` and the bounds checking of the variable as part of a loop, so the user is forced to enter valid number within your specified range

For example, the following code presents the options first, then continually asks the user for valid input until they enter it:

```
// Present the options
Console.WriteLine(" 1. Blue \r\n 2. Yellow \r\n 3. Red \r\n 4. Green");

// This variable will hold their input after the TryParse call 
int ColorChoiceNumberInt;

// Continue to ask for input until they enter an integer between 1 and 4
do
{
    Console.Write("Select a color of Fish by entering the corresponding number (1-4): ");
} while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out ColorChoiceNumberInt) ||
         ColorChoiceNumberInt < 1 ||
         ColorChoiceNumberInt > 4);
```

What I've done in the past is to create a helper function for this, so the logic can be re-used easily throughout the program:

```
public static int GetIntFromUser(string prompt, int minValue = int.MinValue,
    int maxValue = int.MaxValue)
{
    int input;
    do
    {
        Console.Write(prompt);
    } while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out input) ||
             input < minValue ||
             input > maxValue);

    return input;
}
```

With this helper method, your main code is suddenly much more simplified:

```
Console.WriteLine(" 1. Blue \r\n 2. Yellow \r\n 3. Red \r\n 4. Green");
int input = GetIntFromUser("Select a fish color (1-4): ", 1, 4);
Console.WriteLine("You entered: " + input);
```

**Output**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I started answering, but found quite a few issues with your code so it seemed easier to refactor and let you learn by reading a working answer.

Try this:

```
string[] ColorsArray = new string[12] { "blue", "red", "green", "yellow", "blue", "green", "blue", "yellow", "red", "green", "red", "yellow" };
float[] LengthArray = new float[12] { 1.3f, 1.4f, 5.6f, 1.5f, 3.5f, 5.4f, 1.2f, 6.5f, 4.4f, 4.1f, 3.3f, 4.9f };

Console.WriteLine("Select a color of Fish by entering the corresponding number \r\n 1. Blue \r\n 2. Yellow \r\n 3. Red \r\n 4. Green");

bool asking = true;
while (asking)
{
    string ColorChoiceNumber = Console.ReadLine();
    int ColorChoiceNumberInt;
    if (int.TryParse(ColorChoiceNumber, out ColorChoiceNumberInt))
    {
        if (ColorChoiceNumberInt >= 1 && ColorChoiceNumberInt <= 4)
        {
            asking = false;
            string[] fish = new string[] { "Blue", "Yellow", "Red", "Green" };
            Console.WriteLine("The Biggest {0} Fish is Fish Number ", fish[ColorChoiceNumberInt - 1]);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please only enter a number. It must be 1-4.");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Please only enter a number. It must be 1-4.");
    }
}
```